# Exercício de Lançamento de Notas em Python

Tags: python

Oi, sou iniciante na área de programação, e eu tenho um exercício da faculdade para fazer, eu consegui fazer uma parte, mas não sei como programo o resto dele.

É um programa em python de lançamento de notas com três notas por aluno, e cada aluno deve ter um campo para especificar seu nome e sexo, essa parte eu consegui fazer no programa que eu coloquei aí em baixo, mas eu não sei como eu colocaria nesse programa abaixo a outra parte do exercício, se alguém puder me ajudar com isso, eu ficaria muita agradecido.

A outra parte é assim:

Com relação as notas, o programa não pode aceitar notas com números maiores que 10 e notas com números menores que 0, ele tem que retornar uma mensagem para inserir uma nota entre 0 e 10.

Com relação a média, tem que ser assim: média maior ou igual a 7: aprovado, média entre 4 e 6,99: exame, média menor que 4: reprovado (não precisa fazer o print dessa parte agora, só no final).

E então no final do programa, eu preciso que mostre (faça o print) das seguintes coisas:

O total de alunos cadastrados

A porcentagem de alunos aprovados, de exame e reprovados.

E também a quantia de pessoas do sexo feminino aprovado, exame e reprovado e a quantia de pessoas do sexo masculino aprovado, exame e reprovado.

```
ficha = list()
while True:
    nome = str(input("Insira um nome: "))
    sexo = str(input("Insira seu sexo [M/F]: "))
    nota1 = float(input("Insira a nota 1: "))
    nota2 = float(input("Insira a nota 2: "))
    nota3 = float(input("Insira a nota 3: "))
    media = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3) / 3
    ficha.append([nome, sexo, [nota1, nota2, nota3], media])
    resposta = str(input("Quer continuar? [S/N]"))
    if resposta in 'Nn':
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta aqui minha solução, lembrando que não tem validação nos inputs do 'sexo', o programa atende as outras parte na qual você informou. Espero que ajude.

```
ficha = []

while True:

    nome = str(input("Insira um nome: "))
    sexo = str(input("Insira seu sexo [M/F]: "))

    nota1 = float(input("Insira a nota 1: "))
    while nota1 < 0 or nota1 > 10:
        print("Nota invalida, digite um numero entre 0 e 10")
        nota1 = float(input("Insira a nota 1: "))

    nota2 = float(input("Insira a nota 2: "))
    while nota2 < 0 or nota2 > 10:
        print("Nota invalida, digite um numero entre 0 e 10")
        nota2 = float(input("Insira a nota 2: "))

    nota3 = float(input("Insira a nota 3: "))
    while nota3 < 0 or nota3 > 10:
        print("Nota invalida, digite um numero entre 0 e 10")
        nota3 = float(input("Insira a nota 3: "))

    media = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3) / 3
    if media >= 7:
        status = "Aprovado"
    elif media < 7 and media >= 4:
        status = "Exame"
    else:
        status = "Reprovado"

    ficha.append([nome, sexo, [nota1, nota2, nota3], media, status])

    resposta = str(input("Quer continuar? [S/N]"))
    if resposta in 'Nn':
        break

tx_reprovados = 0

tx_exame = 0

tx_aprovado = 0

m_aprovado = 0

f_aprovado = 0

m_exame = 0

f_exame = 0

m_reprovado = 0

f_reprovado = 0

for i in range(0, len(ficha), 1):

    if ficha[i][4] == "Reprovado":
        tx_reprovados += 1
        if ficha[i][1] in 'Ff':
            f_reprovado += 1
        else:
            m_reprovado += 1

    elif ficha[i][4] == "Exame":
        tx_exame += 1
        if ficha[i][1] in 'Ff':
            f_exame += 1
        else:
            m_exame += 1

    elif ficha[i][4] == "Aprovado":
        tx_aprovado += 1
        if ficha[i][1] in 'Ff':
            f_aprovado += 1
        else:
            m_aprovado += 1


print("Taxas de status: ")

print(f'Alunos aprovados: {(tx_aprovado/len(ficha))*100}%')

print(f'Alunos para exame: {(tx_exame/len(ficha))*100}%')

print(f'Alunos reprovados: {(tx_reprovados/len(ficha))*100}%')

print('-' * 45)

print('Visualizacao por sexo:')

print(f'Alunas aprovadas: {f_aprovado}')

print(f'Alunas para exame: {f_exame}')

print(f'Alunas reprovadas: {f_reprovado}')

print('')

print(f'Alunos aprovados: {m_aprovado}')

print(f'Alunos para exame: {m_exame}')

print(f'Alunos reprovados: {m_reprovado}')
```

Comment: Se preferir pode pegar o codigo no git: https://github.com/pabloTecchio/lancamento_notas_escolares

Answer (score 0):

Com relação as notas, o programa não pode aceitar notas com números maiores que 10 e notas com números menores que 0, ele tem que retornar uma mensagem para inserir uma nota entre 0 e 10.

Para essa parte você tem que colocar condicionais, poderia ser dessa forma:

```
if (nota1 > 10 OR nota1 < 0)
nota1 = float(input("inserir uma nota entre 0 e 10:"))
if (nota2 > 10 OR nota2 < 0)
nota2 = float(input("inserir uma nota entre 0 e 10:"))
if (nota > 10 OR nota3 < 0)
nota1 = float(input("inserir uma nota entre 0 e 10:"))
```

Essa é a ideia, dá uma olhada e aprimora o restante. A maior parte da resolução está no uso correto das condicionais.

Comment: Vou tentar implementar essa parte no código, valeu pela ajuda (não fui que coloquei o -1 na sua resposta)